# while entering value into text box, it automatically taking full date default angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I am using input `type="text"` for entering date in my site for angular JS, while entering the text box, it is taking default value is `01/01/2001`

below code I am using :

```
<p ng-controller="DatePickerController" class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="effectiveDate"   ng-model="fieldValue" is-open="opened"  close-text="Close" />
     <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
     </span>
</p>

{{fieldValue}} 01/01/2001
```

could you please help me out any one, Thanks in advance

Comment: help you to what you haven't explained what you want

Comment: Hi @DayanMorenoLeon, i want normal flow and need date validation, while entering 1 it taking 01/01/2001, it shouldn't right, while entering 1 it should take 1 in tetxbox.

Comment: you can do 3 things either create a directive, require ngModel and add a validator or just use ng-pattern and use something like \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} or take a look at https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-date or https://github.com/michaelwinser/input-date and check if you can use it or they deal with it

Comment: your requirement is not clear regarding what are you expecting to have. Can you please let us know by elaborating it in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **date** type in HTML5, then no need to do anything in AngularJS.

```
<input type="date" etc...
```

The FormController will only be $valid if a valid date is provided. You can make this necessary by Just adding a required attribute.

[More info](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html)

Comment: But All browser will not support the type = "date" @JMK